# How to use variable inside useEffect in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am working with Reactjs and i am using Nextjs,Right now i am trying to get value of "Editor",I want to know that
How can i get "variable value" inside "handleSubmit function" ? In other words how can i alert Editor values inside handleSubmit button ?
Here is my current code,Thank you in advance.

```tsx
const [editor, setEditor] = useState()
    
useEffect(() => {
 if(editor){
   const content = editor.getContent();
   console.log('content is ' + content); //How can i pass "content to handlesubmit"
 }
}, [editor])
    
const handleSubmit = async(e: any) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('content is ' + content);
}

// ...

     <Editor
        onInit={(evt, ed) => {
            setEditor(ed);
           }}
        initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor.</p>"
        init={{
          height: 500,
          menubar: false,
          plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
            'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
          ],
          toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | ' +
          'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
          'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
          'removeformat | help',
          content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
        }}
  />
```

Comment: handleSubmit itself contains Editor, where do you want to pass the content? @Phil has suggested the fetching content way.

Comment: I think more relevant code is needed to give better answer, but if editor is initialized once then using `useRef` and refering the current value in `handleSubmit` not work in your case

Answer (score 0):

Just refer to `editor` within your `handleSubmit` function.

It will either be `undefined` if `editor` has not been set when you call `handleSubmit()` or it will be able to return the value of `getContent()`.

If you need to conditionally do something at that point, just check the value

```js
const handleSubmit: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const content = editor?.getContent();
  alert(`content is ${content}`);
  if (content) {
    // ...
  }
};
```

You might want to use some [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to prevent your *form* from existing or being submit-able before `editor` is present...

```jsx
{editor && (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    {/* ... */}
  </form>
)}
```

Comment: giving me following message "content is undefined"

Comment: @Rick that means you're probably calling `handleSubmit` before the `editor` state has been set. Without know where you're using `handleSubmit`, I can't help any further

Comment: i am using "handlesubmit" on form , let me explain i have simple form ( input type text , and editor) and whenever user click on submit button then "handlesubmit" function should work ( should get value of form and pass to API (Axios) , so i can save my form data into database with use of API, Hope you understand my point

Comment: Don't explain here in the comments, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74697877/edit) your question to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)